# ceiling() with TreeMultimap

Tags: java, guava, binary-search-tree, treemap

- Is it possible to extend TreeMultimap from Google's guava to get some king odd `ceiling` function? `ceiling(key)` would return the smallest key greater than the given one. (I know I could get an ordered set view and just look, but I would prefer something with beter time complexity, like a balanced binary search tree offers)
- Is there any other library that would implement a balanced binary search tree and allow that?
- What is the complexity of common operations of TreeMultimap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
multimap.keySet().ceiling(key)
```

does it pretty directly, but you need Java 6 and the most recent Guava release, 14.0, which is when `TreeMultimap.keySet()` [started returning `NavigableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html#keySet%28%29).  The complexity is O(log #keys), exactly as you would expect.

Comment: That's great, thanks. What if I wanted to have some kind of iterator over the key-value pairs, like:
(0,1), (2,1), (2,4), (5,1)
Let's say I am currently on (2,1). Then, ceiling(2) would return (2,4).  Ceiling(3) would return (5,1). Ceiling(1) would return (2,1).

Comment: Not doable with the current API.

Answer (score 0):

```
K ceiling(K key, TreeMultimap<K,V> map) {
  SortedSet<K> keyset = map.keySet();
  SortedSet<K> head = keyset.headSet(key);
  return headSet.isEmpty() ? null : head.last();    
}
```

The documentation doesn't mention any time guarantees for the operations, but I would expect it to run in logarithmic time since both `keySet` and `headSet` appear to return views of the underlying data rather than building new collections themselves.

Comment: I think it's rather keyset.tailsSet(key) and head.first() :)